# Merge to this jQuery

Tags: jquery, merge, this

```
var bottomStack = function () {
                "use strict";
                ...
                jQuery('#bottomstacktitle', this.frame).bind('click', this.toggleFrame);
            };
            var = bottomStackExtends = {
                ...
                toggleFrame: function (animate) {
                    "use strict";
                    if (false !== animate) {
                        animate = true;
                    }
                    this.frame[((animate) ? 'animate' : 'css')]({bottom: (this.bottomStackClosed ?  -180 : 0)});
                    jQuery.cookie("bottomStackClosed", (!this.bottomStackClosed).toString());
                },...
            };
```

When it is running, then debugger says: "Uncaught exception: TypeError: Cannot convert 'this.frame' to object". Yes, because this the "this" isn't that the "this", but this the "this" is jQuery('#bottomstacktitle', this.frame). So can I merge to this "this" for example: .frame tag?

I tried:

```
var bottomstacktitle = jQuery('#bottomstacktitle', this.frame);
    bottomstacktitle.frame = this.frame;
    bottomstacktitle.bind('click', this.toggleFrame);
```

but not working

Have you any solution?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery to retrieve the closest `frame`:

```
var bottomStack = function () {
  "use strict";
   ...
   jQuery('#bottomstacktitle', this.frame).bind('click', this.toggleFrame);
};

var bottomStackExtends = {
  toggleFrame: function (animate) {
    "use strict";
    var currentFrame = jQuery(this).closest("frame").get(0);

    currentFrame[!!animate ? 'animate' : 'css']({
      bottom: this.bottomStackClosed ? -180 : 0
    });
    jQuery.cookie("bottomStackClosed", !this.bottomStackClosed));
  }
  // ...
};
```

jQuery makes sure that `this` is always pointing to the element that the function works with.

In a `click` handler, it would be the element that received the click (`'#bottomstacktitle'`). Since that element is contained in your frame, you can use `.closest()` to retrieve the right frame object.